# Best way to query a database using an OR statement

Tags: subsonic

I am attemping to create the following sql script into a subsonic query that I can use with a collection:

```
Select * from tableA
where tableA.InvoiceID = @Invoice
and tableA.VersionID = @VersionID
and tableA.ActiveDate >= GetDate()
and (tableB.InActiveDate is null or tableB.InActiveDate <= GetDate())
```

Here is my current code:

```
orders = new OrdersCollection();
query = new SubSonic.Query(Tables.Orders);
query.WHERE("InvoiceID", Invoice.InvoiceID);
query.AND("VersionID", version.VersionID);
query.AND("ActiveDate", SubSonic.Is.LessThanOrEqualTo(System.DateTime.Now.ToString()).Value);
query.AND("InActiveDate", SubSonic.Comparision.Is, null).OR("InActiveDate", SubSonic.Is.GreaterThanOrEqualTo("System.DateTime.Now.ToString()).Value);
```

query.CommandTimeOut = intSubSonicTimeOut;
partXrefColl.Load(FilePartXref.FetchByQuery(query));

The problem that I think I am running into is that the evaulation of the dates and the OR statement. I have tried it with just the InvoiceID and VersionID and I get data back to the collection.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You SQL shows a "less than or equal to" operator (<=), but you code says GreaterThanOrEqualTo(). Could the reversal of the logic cause your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the correct syntax for the sql query should have been:

```
Select * from tableA
where tableA.InvoiceID = @Invoice
and tableA.VersionID = @VersionID
and tableA.ActiveDate <= GetDate()
and (tableB.InActiveDate is null or tableB.InActiveDate >= GetDate())
```

And the Code should have been:

```
orders = new OrdersCollection();
query = new SubSonic.Query(Tables.Orders);
query.WHERE("InvoiceID", Invoice.InvoiceID);
query.AND("VersionID", version.VersionID);
query.AND("ActiveDate", SubSonic.Is.LessThanOrEqualTo(System.DateTime.Now.ToString()).Value);
query.AND("InActiveDate", SubSonic.Comparision.Is, null).OR("InActiveDate", SubSonic.Is.GreaterThanOrEqualTo("System.DateTime.Now.ToString()).Value);
```

orders.Load(Invoices.FetchByQuery(query);

Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess:

"SubSonic.Comparision.Is, null" is not mapping to "IS NULL", instead it's mapping to "= NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SubSonic 2.1 or above you can write that query as:

```
OrdersCollection orders = DB.Select.From(Orders.Schema)
  .Where(Orders.Columns.InvoiceID).IsEqualTo(1)
  .And(Orders.Columns.VersionID).IsEqualTo(1)
  .And(Orders.Columns.ActiveDate).IsLessThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.Now)
  .AndExpression(Orders.Columns.InActiveDate).IsNull()
  .Or(Orders.Columns.InActiveDate).IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.Now)
  .ExecuteAsCollection<OrdersCollection>();
```

The AndExpression will cause the Or constraint after it to be nested

Answer (score 0):

Adam has it exactly - the thing you're missing is the Expression part of it which is given with AndExpression

Answer (score 0):

After a little debugging I was able to complete the query with the following:

```
 OrderColl =  DB.Select().From(Orders.Schema)
                    .Where(Orders.Columns.VersionID).IsEqualTo(version.VersionID)
                    .And(Orders.Columns.FulfillNumber).IsEqualTo(invoice.InvocieID)
                    .And(Orders.Columns.ActiveDate).IsLessThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.Now)
                    .AndExpression(Orders.Columns.InactiveDate).IsNull()
                    .Or("InActiveDate").IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.Now)
                    .ExecuteAsCollection<OrdersCollection>();
```

Thanks to everyone for all of your assistance.